# Javascript getElementsByClassName error handling

Tags: javascript

I am getting an element using `javascript` like this..

```
var myPage = document.getElementsByClassName("mypage");
console.log('My Page Found : ' + myPage[0].id);
```

This works if the element is found, but if not then it gives error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: myPage[0] is undefined
```

How can I do error handling if it does not find the element?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Its a collection so check the length before you try to access elements in it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Deeper understanding what is going on:

```
var myPage = document.getElementsByClassName("mypage");
```

works as intended. It is not finding any "mypage" elements to it is returning an empty HTMLCollection.
Now you try to access a property of this collection that is not set. That results in an `undefined` value. Thats causing the Error.

Undefined is a primitive not configurable, writable or enumerable. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

How to avoid that?
In general it is best practise to check if a value is valid before using it.

Avoid using `if (myPage === undefined)`. This is semi-optimal practise because it will throw an error if your comparing variable is not defined.
If you want to check if something is defined use error-save `if (typeof === 'undefined')` or the `??` operator like `myPage ?? mypage[0]`. If you work with the newest EcmaScript you can use the `?.` operator with `??` like `myPage?.[0] ?? 'sorry, no mypage found'`.

The last two things I would suggest is using `try { /*your code*/ } catch(e) { /*handle Error e*/}`.

Also read something about `var, let` and `const`. Since EcmaScript6 there are very few use cases for using `var` over `let` or `const`. (see https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining for more information about the experimental `.?` operator.

**EDIT:**
Edited the answer after the 'friendly hints' of the community. Thank you

Comment: _"It is not finding any "mypage" elements to it is returning `undefined`"_ - That's not correct. `.getElementsByClassName()` will _always_ return a live `HTMLCollection`. In this case the collection is empty.

Comment: _"Avoid using if (myPage === undefined)"_ - Because it would always be `false`...

Comment: _"This is non-standard and may not be supported in all configurations"_ - What? o.O

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? This thing is full of errors or strange assumptions...

Comment: `=== undefined` is universally supported.... optional chaining and  nullish coalescing are not (yet)

Comment: Try using (x === undefined) if x is not declared. Good luck with the resulting error. (typeof x === 'undefined') does not throw an error.

Comment: The variable in question is already declared. You are going way down strange rabbit holes here

Comment: @charlietfl  As you can read in my (originial) post it was a suggestion to avoid that pattern. I didn't it would not work in this specific example.

Comment: Fine but that is all based on a false premise of what `getElementsByClassName()` will return in the first place. Introducing something and then saying not not use it will just confuse OP. Best to just stick to the specific issues in the question. Practical vs academic approach

Answer (score 1):

Use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and the Nullish operators:

```js
var myPage = document.getElementsByClassName("mypage");
console.log('My Page Found : ' + (myPage[0]?.id ?? '[none]'));
```

EDIT (polyfill based on Babel's polyfill):

```js
// #section Polyfills
function optionalChain(source, item) {
    var _chained;
    return (_chained = source) === null || _chained === undefined ? undefined : _chained[item];
}

function nullishRet(item, default) {
    var _nullishc;
    return (_nullishc = item) !== null && _nullishc !== undefined ? _nullishc : default;
}
// #endsection

var myPage = document.getElementsByClassName("mypage");
console.log('My Page Found : ' + nullishRet(optionalChain(myPage, 'id'), '[none]'));
```

should do it.

Comment: this solution won't work in all chrome versions below 80 and will not even work in any Internet Explorer. Check doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Experimental feature. https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining

Comment: @KaiLehmann Nope. It's standard now. All latest browsers (excluding IE) have it (and Node >14)

Comment: @LoganDevine https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining ~89% support. Breaks the app on ~11% of the users for saving a few chars of code. It's not a great deal to write polyfill for that and raising your support to 99%.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element is undefined; if it's not undefined, check the `0th` index.

**Like this:**

```
var myPage = document.getElementsByClassName("mypage");
if (myPage && myPage[0] && myPage[0].id) console.log('My Page Found : ' + myPage[0].id);
else console.log('My Page Not Found')
```

**The best thing about this solution is that it is compatible with all older browsers.**

Comment: Can even become shorter: if (myPage[0]?.id) ..., Also keep in mind that he didn't say that the log should not be shown if it does not exist.

Comment: @SeppeMariën it can, but the thing is that we should care about the readability of the code too.

Comment: That's why I gave you this comment you are doing 3 and operators to check if one property exist.

Comment: @SeppeMariën I agree with your point, I can also use that approach, but to make the user understand the answer, I created a simple solution. With that operator, there is a big chance the user will get confused about what's going on there. It's a good idea to simplify things.

Comment: @SeppeMariën the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) doesn't support in older browsers.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining --> 89% of global users support it.

Comment: @SeppeMariën so your app will break for 11% of all users just because you want save a few chars of code?

Comment: Yes because you need to need to take in consideration of who those 11% of people are! If you take in consideration that almost the whole world has access to the internet but not everyone is going to use your website. The majority of the 11% are people that don't update their browser because they don't use it for this kind of things. And we can go on with this discussion, but it is actually very simple: if you want full support then your way is better, if you want to support the majority then you can use optional chaining.